# Emberjs - Temporary disable property changes notification

Tags: binding, ember.js, observable

Is there any simple way to achieve a temporary disabling of notifications of an object property or properties?

I know you can defer them with `beginPropertyChanges()` and `endPropertyChanges()` but I don't want those changes to be notified at all until I explicitly enable them.

Thank you in advance.

**Use case:**
I have to set a property of an object (`A`) with another object (`B`). Properties of `B` are being observed by several methods of other objects. At some time the `B` object's data gets cleared and the observers get notified, later an HTTP response sets them with something useful. I would not want the observers get notified when clearing the object because the properties values are not valid at that moment.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example why you want to do that? What is your specific use case?

Comment: I don't think there is.  Check out the source for the observer: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/observer.js.  I don't fully understand exactly how all that works yet, but it looks like everything you need to know is there.  Specifically, `Ember._suspendObserver` and `Ember._suspendListener`, or perhaps even `Ember.removeObserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but it appears high in Google search for suspending observers, so I would comment.

There are evident use cases for such a feature, for example, an enum property of an object is represented by a list box and the object may change. If the list box is used to request property changes from the server and to set the new value on success, the natural way to do things is to use a controller property with the list box, set that property to the object property when the object changes, and observe it to make requests to the server. In this case whenever the object changes the observer will receive an unwanted notification.

However, I agree that these use cases are so diverse that there is no way Ember can support them.

Thus, a possible work around is to declare a variable in the controller and use it whenever you change a property so that you react only to changes made by the User:

```
doNotReact: false,
updateManually: function() {
    this.doNotReact = true; 
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('actions', this, function() {
       this.doNotReact = false;
    });
    ............
    this.set('something', somevalue);
    ............
},

onChange: function() {
    if (this.doNotReact) return;
    ...............
}.observes('something')
```

The value of doNotReact will be reset after the observer gets a chance to run. I do not recommend to reset the stopper variable in the observer since it will not run if you set the property to the same value it already has.

Answer (score 2):

Ember doesn't support suspending notifications. I would strongly suggest against toying with the private APIs mentioned in the above comments.

I wonder why you bother clearing the object's data prior to the HTTP request? Seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

Using a flag will cause the computed to still trigger.

The best I've come up with is to override the computed with the last known value. Later you can enable it by setting the computed property definition again.

```
let _myComputedProperty = Ember.computed('foobar', function() {
  let foobar = this.get('foobar');
  console.log('myComputedProperty triggered >', foobar);
  return '_' + foobar + '_';
});

Controller.extend({
  turnOffComputed: function() {
    let myComputedProperty = this.get('myComputedProperty');
    this.set('myComputedProperty', myComputedProperty);
  },

  turnOnComputed: function() {
    this.set('myComputedProperty', _myComputedProperty);
  }
})
```

Full example: [Conditional binding for a computed property](https://ember-twiddle.com/8ae1a91e6a625da3882981843b3d1e5a?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)